# Change text of blue bar that shows " is using your location" on home screen like uber app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-location, cllocationmanager

[image]

I'm using location manager, requestWhenInUseAuthorization. When my app goes into the background, the blue bar appears that shows "My app name is using your Location".

I tried some privates UIApplication private API

```
let mutableString = NSMutableString(string: "test")
let number = NSNumber(integer: i)
let bool = NSNumber(bool: false)


UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector(Selector("setDoubleHeightStatusText:forStyle:"), withObject: mutableString, withObject: number)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector(Selector("addStatusBarStyleOverrides:"), withObject: number)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector(Selector("setGlowAnimationEnabled:forStyle:"), withObject: bool, withObject: number)
```

But i can't change the text! What's wrong with my code

Comment: Are you sure, you can change that text? I guess you can change your app name not the rest of the text.

Comment: i'm sure we can, but i dont know how!

Comment: Did you find the solution @ChauDuongKhong ?